# Putting the check for if user is logged in or not into an include file in php

Tags: php, include, server-side

I have a code to check whether the user is logged in or not
this is the code
call the userlog.php

```
    <?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['idx'])) { 
if (!isset($_COOKIE['idCookie'])) {
$logOptions = '<a href="register.php">Register Account</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
echo $logOptions;
}
}
else{//do something }
```

This code works fine if I include this code in all the files as it is.
When I put the file into a separate file and include it into all the files it is not executing properly.
The else condition is different for all the files so I have If I start the else block in the include file itself then when I end the else block in this file (call index.php) then there is error

```
syntax error, unexpected '}' in index.php on line 43
```

and when I put the else in the index.php file and if block in the userlog.php then following error occurs

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in index.php on line 9
```

So how can I use the include to manage this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the proper open and close braces. In the code you have given your else block is not eding. You have commented out that part of code. I am referencing this line

```
else{//do something }
```

Create the proper `if-else` block and include, that should solve this error.

In an IDE like eclipse you can quickly jump to the matching braces using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  to verify.

Answer (score 1):

***inc.php***

```
<?php
$loggedIn = FALSE;

if ( !isset($_SESSION['idx']) ) { 
    if ( !isset($_COOKIE['idCookie']) ) {
        $logOptions = '<a href="register.php">Register Account</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
        echo $logOptions;
    }
} else {
    $loggedIn = TRUE;
}
?>
```

***index.php***

```
<?php
require_once('inc.php');

if ( $loggedIn == TRUE ) {
    // do your stuff
}
?>
```

Comment: that should do it yes. Trying thisn now